# How do I use NHibernate CreateCriteria for joins with possible null value?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

NHibernate Version: 3.3.1

The original query is as follows.

```
List<PostInstruction> instructions = PostInstruction.Query(
    Restrictions.Eq("Campaign", campaign),
    Restrictions.In("Status", new PostInstructionStatus[] { 
                PostInstructionStatus.Pending, 
                PostInstructionStatus.Finished 
                }),
    Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Gt("DateCreated", DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)),
        Restrictions.IsNotNull("Post")
        )
    );
```

We were only using it for a Count functionality, so I converted it to only return the count, but ran into a problem. I have to do two separate queries in order to account for null Post values. Is there a way I can do the following in a single query?

```
    public static int CountByCampaignCity(Campaign campaign, City city)
    {
        int finished, pending;

        using (ISession session = DataAccess.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Type objectType = typeof(PostInstruction);
                ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(objectType);

                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Campaign", campaign));
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("City", city));
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", PostInstructionStatus.Finished));

                criteria.CreateCriteria("Post").Add(Restrictions.In("Status", new PostStatus[] { PostStatus.Pending, PostStatus.Live }));
                criteria.SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("Id"));

                finished = int.Parse(criteria.UniqueResult().ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                    transaction.Rollback();

                throw;
            }
        }

        using (ISession session = DataAccess.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Type objectType = typeof(PostInstruction);
                ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(objectType);

                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Campaign", campaign));
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("City", city));
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Post", null));
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Status", PostInstructionStatus.Pending));
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Gt("DateCreated", DateTime.UtcNow - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)));
                criteria.SetProjection(Projections.CountDistinct("Id"));

                pending = int.Parse(criteria.UniqueResult().ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
                if (transaction != null)
                    transaction.Rollback();

                throw;
            }
        }

        return pending + finished;
    }
```

Comment: What version of nHibernate are you running? ...and just out of curiosity: Why do you start a transaction before each query?

Comment: Using 3.3.1, and because I just copy pasted the code to get it running while I try and figure out how to do it in one query.

Comment: Did my answer below help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

With a QueryOver you should be able to do something like this:

```
var instructionsCount = session.QueryOver<PostInstruction>()
    .Select(Projections.Count<PostInstruction>(pi => pi.Id))
    .Where(pi => pi.Campaign == campaign && pi.City == city && (pi.Post == PostStatus.Pending || pi.Post == PostStatus.Live || pi.Post == null)); //Add your other conditions

Console.WriteLine(instructionsCount.SingleOrDefault<int>());
```